# Installing Windows 7 manually with new laptops

Tags: windows-7, reinstall, bloatware

I've purchased a few laptops that only come with Restore partitions. I can buy restore media (which I can create myself), but they will not provide an actual Windows 7 DVD.

The brands are Lenovo, ASUS, and MSI.

I have legitimate license keys (which are included), but I don't think I can use those to install Windows 7 directly from a DVD.

What can I do about this? How can I legally install Windows 7, without all the crapware, and use my legal keys?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you use an OEM disk other than one supplied by your manufacturer, your new installation of Windows will not activate with Microsoft after install. If you use a retail disk (or trial version as someone else has commented) then your key won't work at all.

Your best bet is to manually remove the crapware (as annoying as it is), or try using something like [the PC Decrapifier](http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/).

Unfortunately, though your key is legitimate, you've bought a PC with a license to use Windows 7 on that hardware; you haven't bought a license to use Windows 7. This means the Manufacturer must supply you with the media. It's frustrating, but that is Microsoft's licensing model.

Answer (score 1):

Download a trial version, burn it to DVD, and install from there...then plug in your keys maybe? FWIW...